# Integrate Firebase in a Flutter module embedded in an iOS app

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, flutter-module

**Adding Firebase to a Flutter module embedded in an iOS app**

I have successfully integrated my `Flutter module` into an `iOS app` and have been able to build and run the app.

Also, I have successfully integrated `Firebase` into my `iOS native app`.

**Now**, I am facing a challenge in `setting up Firebase for the Flutter module within the iOS app`.
The Flutter module does NOT have an iOS folder where I can easily add the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file in the Runner folder.

Also, when running the `FlutterFire CLI`, an error occurs stating that there is `no iOS app to create a project for` because no iOS folder in the module.

> Additionally, the module cannot access the native folder to locate and utilize the GoogleService-Info.plist file.

Given these constraints, how to add Firebase to a Flutter module within an iOS app?

> P.S.: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73277119/12290240) is incorrect!